# Trouble converting function from vmm.dll (C) to vmmsharp.dll (C#). (DMA) (PCILEECH) (C#)

Tags: c#, c, type-conversion, dma

I am attempting to bring over a function from [vmmdll.h](https://github.com/ufrisk/MemProcFS/blob/master/vmm/vmmdll.h) to [vmmsharp.cs](https://github.com/ufrisk/MemProcFS/blob/master/vmmsharp/vmmsharp.cs). In this case, I am trying to bring over Map_GetPool.

You can see here my implementation to C#:

```
//Please view the images:
```

[Bringing function over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjN2r.png)

```
    internal static uint VMMDLL_POOLMAP_FLAG_ALL = 0;
    internal static uint VMMDLL_POOLMAP_FLAG_BIG = 1;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal unsafe struct VMMDLL_MAP_POOLENTRYTAG
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)] internal char[] szTag;
        //szTag struct 
        /*internal uint dwTag;
        internal uint _Filler;
        internal uint cEntry;
        internal uint iTag2Map;*/
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal unsafe struct VMMDLL_MAP_POOLENTRY
    {
        internal ulong va;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)] internal char[] szTag;
        //szTag struct 
        /*internal uint dwTag;
        internal byte _ReservedZero;
        internal byte fAlloc;
        internal byte tpPool;
        internal byte tpSS;*/

        internal uint cb;
        internal uint _Filler;
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal unsafe struct VMMDLL_MAP_POOL
    {
        internal uint dwVersion;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)] internal uint[] _Reserved1;
        internal uint cbTotal;
        internal uint* piTag2Map;
        internal VMMDLL_MAP_POOLENTRYTAG* pTag;
        internal uint cTag;
        internal uint cMap;
        internal VMMDLL_MAP_POOLENTRY[] pMap;
    }

    [DllImport("vmm.dll", EntryPoint = "VMMDLL_Map_GetPoolEx")]
    internal static extern unsafe bool VMMDLL_Map_GetPoolEx(
        byte* pNetMap,
        ref uint pcbNetMap);
```

[Implementing it into c#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crIxq.png)

```
//My map pool
    public unsafe struct MAP_POOL
    {
        public uint dwVersion;
        public uint[] _Reserved1;
        //public unsafe fixed uint _Reserved1[6];
        public uint cbTotal;
        public uint[] piTag2Map;
        public MAP_POOLENTRYTAG* pTag;
        public uint cTag;
        public uint cMap;
        public MAP_POOLENTRY[] pMap;
    }


    //szTag[5] -> POOLENTRY 4th tpPool MAP_POOL_TYPE 5th tpSS MAP_POOL_TYPE_SUBSEGMENT
    public enum MAP_POOL_TYPE
    {
        MAP_POOL_TYPE_Unknown = 0,
        MAP_POOL_TYPE_NonPagedPool = 1,
        MAP_POOL_TYPE_NonPagedPoolNx = 2,
        MAP_POOL_TYPE_PagedPool = 3
    }

    public enum MAP_POOL_TYPE_SUBSEGMENT
    {
        VMM_MAP_POOL_TYPE_SUBSEGMENT_UNKNOWN = 0,
        VMM_MAP_POOL_TYPE_SUBSEGMENT_NA = 1,
        VMM_MAP_POOL_TYPE_SUBSEGMENT_BIG = 2,
        VMM_MAP_POOL_TYPE_SUBSEGMENT_LARGE = 3,
        VMM_MAP_POOL_TYPE_SUBSEGMENT_VS = 4,
        VMM_MAP_POOL_TYPE_SUBSEGMENT_LFH = 5
    }

    public unsafe struct MAP_POOLENTRYTAG
    {
        //union
        public char[] szTag;
        /*
         * struct {
        DWORD dwTag;
        DWORD _Filler;
        DWORD cEntry;
        DWORD iTag2Map;
         };
         */
    }

    public unsafe struct MAP_POOLENTRY
    {
        public ulong va;
        public char[] szTag;
        //public unsafe fixed char szTag[5];            
        public uint cb;
        public uint _Filler;

    }
```

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaEeN.png)

```
        public static unsafe MAP_POOLENTRY[] Map_GetPoolEx()
    {
        bool result;
        uint cb = 0;
        int cbMAP = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(vmmi.VMMDLL_MAP_POOL));
        int cbENTRY = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(vmmi.VMMDLL_MAP_POOLENTRY));
        result = vmmi.VMMDLL_Map_GetPoolEx(null, ref cb);
        if (!result || (cb == 0)) { return new MAP_POOLENTRY[0]; }
        fixed (byte* pb = new byte[cb])
        {
            result = vmmi.VMMDLL_Map_GetPoolEx(pb, ref cb);
            if (!result) { return new MAP_POOLENTRY[0]; }
            vmmi.VMMDLL_MAP_POOL pm = Marshal.PtrToStructure<vmmi.VMMDLL_MAP_POOL>((System.IntPtr)pb);
            if (pm.dwVersion != vmmi.VMMDLL_MAP_PHYSMEM_VERSION) { return new MAP_POOLENTRY[0]; }
            MAP_POOLENTRY[] m = new MAP_POOLENTRY[pm.cMap];
            for (int i = 0; i < pm.cMap; i++)
            {
                vmmi.VMMDLL_MAP_POOLENTRY n = Marshal.PtrToStructure<vmmi.VMMDLL_MAP_POOLENTRY>((System.IntPtr)(pb + cbMAP + i * cbENTRY));
                MAP_POOLENTRY e;
                e.va = n.va; 
                e.cb = n.cb;
                e.szTag = n.szTag; 
                //m[i] = e;
            }
            return m;
        }

    }
```

As you can see, the pointer PVMMDLL -> VMMDLL* throws an error stating it can't do that.
For the function, for some reason, **e** is undefined even though it is indeed defined. Also, is my overall setup correct?

Thanks, I appreciate any help.

Here are the links again to the implementations if needed (This doesn't have my implementation in it, but it has other implementations for similar functions):

```
vmmdll: https://github.com/ufrisk/MemProcFS/blob/master/vmm/vmmdll.h#L1506

vmmsharp: https://github.com/ufrisk/MemProcFS/blob/master/vmmsharp/vmmsharp.cs
```

Comment: Does this question involve the C++ language in any way?

Comment: Yes, it involves both c and c# I assume people who know c++ know c.